# Pilot still distributing on TestFlight when skip_submission = true

Tags: fastlane, fastlane-pilot

When using Pilot to upload the build I'm setting `skip_submission: true` but the build is still distributed to internal testers. I was under the impression that only the IPA would be uploaded and it wouldn't go to testing?

```
pilot(
  changelog: "Live",
  skip_submission: true
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your impression is correct, see the discussion at https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/1888

> iTunes connect will automatically distribute any new build to internal
>   testers if testing is enabled for that particular version / build
>   train. Skip submission only prevents fastlane from sending the build
>   for external testing review.